# Elasticsearch datastreams integration with spring data

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

We have time series data & there by moving to use elasticsearch datastreams

I am using springboot, having following dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
  <version>4.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Seems Spring Data stopped working with following error:

```
Error Message: cannot create index with name [my_datastream_index_test], because it matches with template [my-datastream-index-template] that creates data streams only, use create data stream api instead

Caused by: ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=cannot create index with name [my_datastream_index_test], because it matches with template [my-datastream-index-template] that creates data streams only, use create data stream api instead]]
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.BytesRestResponse.errorFromXContent(BytesRestResponse.java:178)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:2484)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseResponseException(RestHighLevelClient.java:2461)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2184)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2154)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:2118)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.create(IndicesClient.java:152)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.RestIndexTemplate.lambda$doCreate$0(RestIndexTemplate.java:86)
    at org.springf
```

Does elastic spring-data work with data streams? I expected it to be seamless transition. Am I missing on anything?

The repository bean itself is not getting created:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is RestStatusException{status=400} org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.RestStatusException: Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=cannot create index with name [my_datastream_index_test], because it matches with template [my-datastream-index-template] that creates data streams only, use create data stream api instead]; nested exception is ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=cannot create index with name [my_datastream_index_test], because it matches with template [my-datastream-index-template] that creates data streams only, use create data stream api instead]]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:224)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.lambda$instantiateClass$5(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:579)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.instantiateClass(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:579)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:544)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:325)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:323)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:231)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:115)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:329)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.java:69)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
    ... 161 more
```

Comment: I think Spring Data tries to create an index `PUT my_datastream_index_test` (i.e. the call to `IndicesClient.create()`) while it should create a data_stream instead `PUT _data_stream/my_datastream_index_test`. Probably related to this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/issues/2089

Comment: Please post it in your question instead of comments

Comment: Yes, but the code is still trying to create `my_datastream_index_test` as an index (see `IndicesClient.create()` in the stack trace)

Answer (score 0):

First, as Val commented, Spring Data Elasticsearch currently creates indexes and no data streams.

But second, according to the error message, the data stream would be created by an index template, I assume. You need to keep Spring Data Elasticsearch from creating the index automatically, you do this by adding the `createIndex` value to the `@Document` annotation of your entity class:

```java
@Document(indexName = "my_datastream_index_test", createIndex = false)
```